Finding $\int_\Gamma \frac{z f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz$ over a given contour
Let $f(z)=z^4-2z^3+2z^2-3z+60$ and let $\Gamma$ be the circle $|z|=5$. I want to find $$\int_\Gamma \frac{z f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz$$
Supposing we had $f'(z)$ in the numerator instead of $z f'(z)$, this would very clearly be solved with the Argument Principle. Here, we cannot use it. So, we investigate using Rouche's theorem. Note that if we let $g(z) = z^4$, then for $z$ on $\Gamma$, we have $|f(z)-g(z)| < 2(5)^3+2(5)^2+3(5)+60 < 5^4 = |g(z)|$ and so since $g$ has four zeros interior to $\Gamma$, then so does $f$. Going back to the integral, we have
\begin{align}
\underbrace{\int_\Gamma \frac{z f'(z)}{f(z)}}_{=I_5} \, dz = \int_\Gamma \frac{z (4z^3-6z^2+4z-3)}{z^4-2z^3+2z^2-3z+60} = \int_\Gamma \frac{4z^4-6z^3+4z^2-3z}{z^4-2z^3+2z^2-3z+60} \tag{1}
\end{align}
Denote the above integral by $I_5$ $($because $\Gamma$ is the curve $|z|=5)$. Now, because $\Gamma$ already contains all the zeros of $f(z)$, then if $I_R$ is the same integral as in $(1)$ except with $\Gamma$ being the curve $|z|=R$, we must have
$$|I_5| = |I_R| \hspace{1cm} \forall \, R \geq 5 \tag{2}$$
So, we get
\begin{align}
|I_5| = |I_R| &= \left| \int_{|z|=R}\frac{z f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz \right| \\
&\leq \int_{|z|=5} \left| \frac{z f'(z)}{f(z)} \, dz \right| \\
&= \int_{|z|=5} \frac{|z f'(z)|}{|f(z)|} \, |dz| \\ 
&= \frac{4R^4-6R^3+4R^2-3R}{R^4-2R^4+2R^2-3R+60} \cdot 2\pi R
\end{align}
But now we have a problem because $|I_R| \to \infty$ as $R \to \infty$. In fact, I suspect that the method I've contrived is problematic because it requires the degree of the numerator to be at least two less than the denominator if you want the integral to vanish if to be at least one less if you want the integral to converge to a nonzero magnitude. In our case, $\deg(z \cdot f'(z)) = \deg(f(z))$ and so the extra $|dz|$ is the final culprit in all this which makes the magnitude of the integral diverge.
Perhaps there is a better way to approach this?

Let
$$ f(z)=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)(z-z_3)(z-z_4) $$
and then
$$ \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}=\sum_{k=1}^4\frac{z}{z-z_k}. $$
So
\begin{align}
&I_5=\int_\Gamma \frac{z f'(z)}{f(z)}\, dz= \int_\Gamma \sum_{k=1}^4\frac{z}{z-z_k}dz=2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^4z_k=4\pi i.
\end{align}

Might be a dumb question, but why $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^4z_k=2?$

@Conreu Apply this to the OP's choice of $f$.

I see, it's simple comparison between original polynomial and the one obtained form multiplying each root binomial. Thanks.

The arguments given in this answer seem to follow perfectly without flaw but I am concerned with the fact that we did not use the contour $\Gamma$ at all. Such a result seems to suggest that the given contour does not matter, but certainly if we let $g=\frac{z f'}{f}$, then $g$ is meromorphic in $\Gamma$ and $\displaystyle\int_\Gamma g=2\pi\displaystyle\sum_k$ Res $a_k$ and so we can obtain various results for $\displaystyle\int_\Gamma g$ depending upon how "large" we make $\Gamma$
